# absolute value of an expression

Tags: absolute-value

This might sound like a really obvious question, but I wanted to make sure.

**Is the absolute value of the expression (-x-1)/(x²+1) = (x+1)/(x²+1) because you can take the minus out and make the expression -(x+1)/(x²+1) and then the absolute value removes the minus sign? Or would it simply be (x-1)/(x²+1)?**

Comment: If $x^2+1$ is positive, it depends on the sign of $x+1$

Comment: x is positive in this expression.

Comment: Then you know the answer

Comment: Neither: $$\left|\frac{-x-1}{x^2+1}\right|=\frac{|x+1|}{x^2+1}\;.$$ The quantity $x^2+1$ is always positive, but we don’t know the sign of $-x-1$; we *do* know, as you said, that $-x-1=-(x+1)$, so that $$|-x-1|=|-(x+1)|=|x+1|\;,$$ and we might as well use the simpler form $|x+1|$, but we still need the absolute value signs: we don’t know whether $x+1$ is positive, negative, or zero. If you know that $x\ge-1$, then of course you can remove the absolute value signs around $x+1$.